# Rewriting a Value in a For Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, xamarin-studio

[ **Resovled.** Thanks again! I dunno why loops always trip me up, haha. ]

Yet another loop question. I think this is going to be my calling card. This time, I'm working with C#. Trying to figure out a good way to phrase this, but say this is my base code:

```
string[] daftChildren = new string[] { "Deidra", "Jolie", "Johnna", 
                                       "Kayben", "Saber", "Adam" };

for (int i = 0; i < daftChildren.Length; i ++) {
    Console.WriteLine(daftChildren[i] + " is a member of the family.");
    if (daftChildren[i] == "Saber") {
        Console.Write("Saber is a part of the family... for now.");
    }
}
```

The code is self explanatory: I'm using the **for loop** to list each member of the family. **If** one of the family members listed is Saber, then it prints "Saber is a part of the family... for now." But here's the rub.

With the above code, my output will print "Saber is a part of the family" and "Saber is a part of the family... for now." How do I write it so **only** if block prints.

I hope I asked this clearly enough. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `if` "Saber" ... `else` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really sneaky way to do it:

```
string[] daftChildren = new string[] { "Deidra", "Jolie", "Johnna", "Kayben", "Saber", "Adam" };

    for (int i = 0; i < daftChildren.Length; i ++) {
        Console.Write(daftChildren[i] + " is a member of the family.");
        if (daftChildren[i] == "Saber") {
            Console.Write(".. for now.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Cheeky! I like this approach. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < daftChildren.Length; i++)
        {
            string outPut = daftChildren[i].Equals("Saber") ? "Saber is a part of the family... for now." : daftChildren[i] + " is a member of the family.";
            Console.WriteLine(outPut);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need an `if..else` statement, like below:

```
if (daftChildren[i] == "Saber") 
{
    Console.Write("Saber is a part of the family... for now.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(daftChildren[i] + " is a member of the family.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < daftChildren.Length; i ++) {
        if(!daftChildren[i].Contains("Saber"))
        {
        Console.WriteLine(daftChildren[i] + " is a member of the family.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Saber is a part of the family... for now.");
        }
```

Comment: why do you have two seperate if's, and one of them you check if the string contains the exact content it should have?

Comment: @Dispersia,  Good call, I edited it to reflect if else.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify SimpleVar

```
 string[] daftChildren = new string[] { "Deidra", "Jolie", "Johnna", "Kayben", "Saber", "Adam" };

        for (int i = 0; i < daftChildren.Length; i ++) {
            if (daftChildren[i] == "Saber") {
                Console.Write("Saber is a part of the family... for now.");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine(daftChildren[i] + " is a member of the family.");
            }
        }
```